# Prove that two integrals are convergent or disvergent simultaneously

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm dealing with a problem for improper integrals reads the following:

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on $[a,+\infty)$, monotonic down to $0$ as $x \to +\infty$. Prove that the following integrals $\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{+\infty} \cos^2 x.f(x)dx$ are convergent or disvergent simultaneously.

I'm quite confused with some words **monotonic down to $0$**. Once I thought that $f(x)$ is simply non-increasing (means if $a \le b$ then $f(a) \ge f(b)$) so that $f(x) \ge \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=0, \quad \forall x \in [a,+\infty)$. Therefore, 
$$0\le \cos^2 x.f(x) \le f(x), \quad \forall x \in [a,+\infty).$$
This means that, the integrals $\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{+\infty} \cos^2 x.f(x)dx$ are convergent or disvergent simultaneously.

Is my solution correct? Otherwise, if is just equipped the assumption that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=0$ without the non-increasing property. How can I come up with another proof?

Comment: From the inequality $0\le f(x)\cos^2x\le f(x)$ you can deduce only that if $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is convergent so is $\int_a^\infty f(x)\cos^2x\,dx$, and that if $\int_a^\infty f(x)\cos^2x\,dx$ is divergent, so is $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre You're right. My proof had lots of mistakes. By reviewing some materials I testify that **$f$ is monotonic down to $0$ as $x \to +\infty$** just means $f$ is monotonic and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** For the harder direction, without loss of generality we may assume that we are integrating from $0$. Let $I_n=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\cos^2 x \,dx$.

The sum $\sum I_n$ converges. Let $J_n=\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\pi/4} f(x)\cos^2 x\,dx$. Then $\sum J_n$ converges.

Let $K(n)=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\,dx$. Conclude that $\sum K(n)$ converges.

Comment: Dear @AndréNicolas, what do you mean by Let $I_n=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} f(x)\cos^2 x f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: I mean that I have a typo. Couldn't make up my mind whether to put $f(x)$ in front or behind, so did both. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your outline. First, suppose $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \cos^2 xf(x)dx$ converges then the sum $\sum I_n$ converges. Now I have two questions:
**1.** Why does $\sum J_n$ converge? Since we haven't proved $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$, so we don't have $J_n \le I_n$.
**2.** If $\sum J_n$ does converge. Why $\sum K(n)$ converges?

Comment: In your proof of the convergence of $\sum J_n$, you will have to use the fact that $f$ decreases monotonically to $0$. Well, at this stage you use very little of that, just the fact that it implies that $f(x)\ge 0$. Later you will need more. For your second question, here we will use decreasing to $0$.